# Why is the material looking better in the layout workspace than in the shading workspace?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, 3d-view, shaders, workspaces

What the title says. My material look lighter and worse in the shading worksapce and in the actual render. Why is that and how to change it so that the material could look like in the default layout.

[image: In the layout]
[image: in the shading workspace]

Comment: The solid view uses the default shading, if you want to render it like that you can try using the Workbench render. Otherwise you'll have to setup your materials properly to render the way you want.

Comment: THe shading workspace uses lookdev by default, which automatically adds an HDRI background. It seems that this is giving your model too much light, causing it to look bad. I would just avoid using lookdev in this case.